# Get The Username/User Id Of Currently Logged In User In A UWP App

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app

I want to get the `username` or user `id` of the currently logged in user in a UWP app. Below is the code that I am using but it returns `null`.

```
var current = users.Where(p => p.AuthenticationStatus == UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated && p.Type == UserType.LocalUser).FirstOrDefault();
var data = await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName);
Username = (string)data;
```

Comment: I don't know of which type is the variable **current**. But are you shure that it has AccountName property? for the sake of clarity try to temporarily avoid **var**. or when you try to write **current.** what does the intellisense offer you, is there such property?

Comment: its of type Windows.System.User and yes it has AccoutName property but returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var users = await User.FindAllAsync(UserType.LocalUser);
var user = (string) await users.FirstOrDefault().GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName);
var domain = "";
var host = "";

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
{
var domainWithUser = (string) await users.FirstOrDefault().GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.DomainName);
domain = domainWithUser.Split('\\')[0];
user = domainWithUser.Split('\\')[1];
}
```

This helped me. reference http://codegur.com/33736983/get-environment-variables-in-net-core-uwp