# Load string with placeholder with user name

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have the following XAML code

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid Margin="50">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="70"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" x:Uid="Greeting"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Then, I created a resource file per language (one for en-US and another for fr-FR) which contains the following resource.

**Name**: Greeting.Text
**Value**: Hello {0}!

The thing is that at run-time, I would like to have my name replaced by the placeholder so I end up with something like Hello Peter Pan!

Ideally, the name (Peter Pan) should come from the Windows system

Who does the code behind look like? I haven't been able to find out anything like that on internet so not sure if that's even possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can divide your *TextBlock* like this:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light">
    <Run x:Uid="Greeting"/>
    <Run Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

However in the code behind you have to define a property *Name* which will return the user's name. Haven's tried, but maybe those will help: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33394019/2681948), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36785526/2681948).

Comment: You can set the different foreground in run, can use hyperlink in it.