# How can I get username or id of currently logged in user in UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp

I found this article: [Get The Username/User Id Of Currently Logged In User In A UWP App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785526/get-the-username-user-id-of-currently-logged-in-user-in-a-uwp-app)

to get the username of current user logged in in uwp app , but when I tried the accepted answer , it returns null/empty , is there any updated version of that?

NOTE: Iam using a microsoft account

UPDATE: All properties from "KnownUserProperties" returns empty string except for "First Name" & "Last Name"

Thanks

Comment: Did enable the User Account Information in the package.appxmanifest ?

Comment: what is that? let me do a research on that

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IReadOnlyList<User> users = await User.FindAllAsync();

    var current = users.Where(p => p.AuthenticationStatus == UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated && 
                                p.Type == UserType.LocalUser).FirstOrDefault();

    // user may have username
    var data = await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName);
    string displayName = (string)data;

    text1.Text = displayName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did enable the User Account Information in the package.appxmanifest ?[image]

Here is the image which shows the manifest file.

Comment: Okay , after that Iam able to retrieve users info using User.FindAllAsync? Thanks

Comment: I enabled the user account info from package manifest , but still returning empty string on AccountName , but if tried first name able to return the first name.

Comment: @NicoTing AccountName is always null for us, I suspect the accountname may requires a permission that is not open to normal developer. The suggested thread from your OP also used domain name, not from the account name.