# In Xamarin UWP apps, How to get currently Windows logged-in User details

Tags: xamarin, uwp, adal, xamarin.uwp

I need to use Windows authentication in my Xamarin UWP app. How can i access currently logged-in user details in the app. Need to retrieve user Active Directory login ID who currently logged in Windows.

I already tried below solution and it gives empty results for me.

[How can I get username or id of currently logged in user in UWP App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47708297/how-can-i-get-username-or-id-of-currently-logged-in-user-in-uwp-app)

Appreciate your help....

Comment: Add user account info to your manifest and retrieve the `DomainName`, you can then split the domain off the string

Comment: Already tried this. But DomainName gives empty value.

Comment: Are you using [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet) for authentication?

Comment: Yes. We are using ADAL

Answer (score 1):

If you have not add [**User Account Information**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) capability to your app in the Package.appxmanifest, you will not have permission to access user account info.

[image]

For other reasons, if you authinticated using hotmail, you need `KnownUserProperties.FirstName` and `KnownUserProperties.LastName` to get your account name.

```
private async void GetUser()
{
    IReadOnlyList<User> users = await User.FindAllAsync();

    var current = users.Where(p => p.AuthenticationStatus == UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated &&
                                p.Type == UserType.LocalUser).FirstOrDefault();

    // user may have username
    var data = await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName);
    string displayName = (string)data;

    // authinticated using hotmail 
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName))
    {

        string a = (string)await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.FirstName);
        string b = (string)await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.LastName);
        displayName = string.Format("{0} {1}", a, b);
    }
}
```

Please note the above code only works in UWP native project, and it can't be used directly in the pcl, you need to create  `GetUser` method via [`DependencyService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction).

**Update**

If you have authorized with ADAL, you could use `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method get info from token cache silently, for more refer [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token).

Comment: I tried with Native UWP project. Still its not working. All KnownUserProperties properties gives empty string. Is it because of any  security restrictions applied in Windows?

Comment: If you have authorized, you could use `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method get info from token cache for more refer [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token).

Comment: @Cin: did you manage to solve this? i have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [UWP sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget) that uses ADAL. ADAL.NET does not expose directly the notion of user from an authentication context. It does provide a `UserInfo`, as a property of the `AuthenticationResult`. When you get back the auth result, you can use the UserInfo property to get the Displayable ID of the signed in user.

Here's more from the [ADAL wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/User-management).

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple. You should do it at the platform specific level, using `Windows.System.User`, To retrieve the current user's information. [Here is a post](https://doumer.me/get-the-device-current-user-name-with-xamarin-forms/) which describes detaily how to accomplish this.